# What is the difference between current->link->data and current->data in singly linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, implementation

I was wondering if `current->link->data` data and `current->data` provides the same result.

Also another concept what exactly the difference between `current` and `current->link` in singly linked list?

Comment: this entirely depends on the implementation of a linked-list in question--you should provide more detail if you expect an adequate answer; my suspicion, however, is that `current->link` points to the *next* element in the list, so the difference is between the current list element data (`current->data`) and that of its successor (`current->link->data`)

Comment: Adding to what **oldrinb** said: You are also more likely to deference a null pointer, when you have twice the indirection in a single statement.

Comment: @oldrinb http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-linked-list-which-is-sorted-how-will-you-insert-in-sorted-way/

Comment: @StoryTeller: it depends entirely on the LL implementation, whether its "contract" with the user guarantees that `current-> link` is never null. (Presumably `current` itself is never null, unless the implementation really sucks.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was wondering if current->link->data data and current->data provides
>   the same result.

May be they provide same data if same data is stored, but these are different locations i.e. if `current->data` is `data` at `current node` then `current->link->data` would be `data` of `next node`. as shown in figure.

```
struct node
{
struct node *link;
int          data;
};
```

Consider a typical `node` of singly linked list, as mentioned above. The member `link` points to `NULL` initially but later on it points to some other `node`. Consider a linked list with some preinserted `node`.

> And also another concept what exactly the difference between current
>   and current->link in singly linked list?

`current` is pointer to current `node` while `current->link` is pointer to next `node` to current `node`.

[image]